# Java exec() function arguments

Tags: java, process

What is the difference between this-

```
Process process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
  new String[] {"cmd", "/c", command.toString()},
  null, new File("D:/test"));
```

and this-

```
Process process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
  command.toString(), null, new File("D:/test"));
```

If I use the first one it's working but if I use the second one it's giving below exception-

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "gst" (in directory "D:\test"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:617)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)
    at CommandInvoker.main(CommandInvoker.java:38)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:385)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:136)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1022)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: Can't find the program `gst`. As it says. Clearly. The difference is that the first version runs a command prompt, as it also says, clearly, which might somehow affect the effective PATH.

Comment: @EJP what is the effective PATH and how is it affecting? Can you please explain?
And for `gst` the same program is running for the first version of code.

Comment: Read the Microsoft Windows documentation on the %PATH% environment variable, and what it means.